# How to achieve such a dropdownlist using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I'm very new to UI development, I want to achieve a drop-down list using **jQuery**, when clicking the `select`, the list will drop-down, and the page below the list will also move down together.

Anyone can give me some advices? How to describe this kind of effect? So I can do some research and Test.

It's just like the top Edition menu on http://www.goal.com

Answer (score 0):

There are already available plugins that create this same exact feel.

try flexbox

http://www.fairwaytech.com/flexbox/flexbox-demos/

Comment: Thank you for reply, but how to make the following page to  move together with the list , so the list will not hide the following page.

Comment: what do you mean 'page to move together with the list'?